# Set an implicit function return in Scala

Tags: scala, dsl

I am writing DSL (domain specific language for my code).
The code is:

```
class NeuronGroupDSL(identifier: String)(implicit network: N2S3SimulationDSL ) // declared values which must be provided by the user, [we can just give a default constructor to this]
 {
  implicit val sizeDefault : Int = 28 // added the implicit default value for the setNumberOfNeurons method
  val id: String = identifier // We can add a default constructor with the Id and the network to this too allow user to skip this part
  var neuronGroup: Option[NeuronGroupRef] = None // this variable stores all the information by using the get property and a associated function with it
  private var neuronParameters: Seq[(Property[_], _)] = Seq()
  private var neuronModel: NeuronModel = _

/**Properties of the NeuronGroupDSL **/
// Added a default size to the size variable
  def ofSize(implicit size: Int): NeuronGroupDSL = {
    this.neuronGroup.get.setNumberOfNeurons(size)
    this
  }
// Give user the opportunity to choose the type of available models by the help of pattern matching
/**Neuron Model:
1. Linear leaky integrate-and-fire model
2. FitzHugh-Nagumo model
3. Izhikevich model
**/
  def modeling(model: NeuronModel): NeuronGroupDSL = {
    this.neuronModel = model
    this.neuronGroup.get.setNeuronModel(model, this.neuronParameters)
    this
  }
//we can define a default property the neuron group model here
  def withParameters(properties: (Property[_], _)*): NeuronGroupDSL = {
    this.neuronParameters = properties
    this.neuronGroup.get.setNeuronModel(this.neuronModel, properties)
    this
  }
}
```

As you can see the definitions `ofSize` `modeling` `withParameters` have the same return type, so is it possible to implicitly define their return type and define these functions without their return part ?

Please help me I want to minimize the code as much as possible.

I too want to know that is it possible to use `case class` , `concise lambda syntax` in this code to further minimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply drop the return type, it will be inferred automatically:

```
def ofSize(implicit size: Int) = {
  neuronGroup.get.setNumberOfNeurons(size)
  this
}
```

Comment: Scala compiler works faster if You explicitly define return types.

Comment: But how the compiler implicitly infer the return type because I never defined it. Please help.

Comment: Does `this` present at end of each function definition tell the return type?

Comment: The return type is just the type of `this`. The `this`-reference has type `NeuronGroupDSL`. There are no generics, no higher kinds, no complicated variance annotations or least upper bound computations. I doubt that the slowdown caused by the omitted return type will be detectable.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. Also, please can you help me to further reduce the code by `case class `, `concise lambda syntax` if possible @AndreyTyukin

Comment: @AnimeshSrivastava What exactly do you wanna do with those? I don't see how these language features are useful here. You have a single class with three setters, what do you want to optimize here at all...

Comment: @AndreyTyukin actually I have a set of files and an already build Domain Specific Language I am just working to minimize the code for better readability and usage.